# How do answers get deleted from Stack Overflow? and how can I see the history?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I posted a question:

[Use a URL to link to a Google map with a marker on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582834/use-a-url-to-link-to-a-google-map-with-a-marker-on-it?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I am no guru... on anything ;-) but i did answer this question myself as I noticed just afterwards that there was one solution.

Later on I noticed that someone else had put in an answer with some more information about the preferred method.. great I thought I will check that out when I get a moment, test that method and give the contributor his dues...

So I went in now to have a look and my answer is gone!

I am looking through my profile and I cannot find where i would see the actual history of my account?

Specifically what I actually posted, who edited it and when etc. I know that you can do this to edits on questions made by other people but what about deleted answers?

Or am I just delusional and I never answered the question? ;-)

Comment: jeezo, i think i may have to look at alternatives to stack overflow... ask a question and it is legitimately migrated here, but i had to create another account on meta stack overflow to get access to it.

Comment: either you can ask questions about stack overflow on stack overflow, or there is a discussion section or your account applies on both

Comment: you are delusional, you are not making any sense...you are hysterical.(slaps gordatron on his face)

Comment: also how many less people are seeing this question now it has been migrated?

Comment: he he thanks Emre I needed that.... now back to work ;-)

Comment: maybe your little cousin deleted your post when he was playing with your computer?Happens to me all the time...

Comment: good point, i also just added a short cut on my home screen of my phone, maybe it was a pocket at it again... last time it was posting on facebook for me ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as 10K+ member I can see deleted posts as well.. and in your question there are no such posts.

I believe that such things also appear in the question [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6582834/timeline), and there's no answer posted except for Allen's.

Bottom line, you probably never posted the answer you wanted, or forgot to click the Submit button, or clicked but something went wrong.

Comment: Correct. There are no deleted answers to that question.

Comment: I assume he was trying to post the answer too soon and missed the error message then.

Comment: I thought that was the case: what every I had done one way or another never hit the server... my answer was there though and showing above the one that was added as i compared the code on the page. make me wish i used those screen capture apps that help with this type of thing

Comment: Next time i post a question I will have to have a play and see how i managed it...

Comment: @gor good idea.. maybe you're into some bug here. :)

Answer (score 1):

**History,**

Click on your name, then activity.

As far as **deleted questions** are concerned, original poster can cast a vote to delete (effective immediately in certain conditions) as well as 3k+ Users. When reaching a threshold, question is deleted. I bet it's 5 or 10.

Moderators can also close/delete question with immediate effect.

Comment: what about answers though?

Comment: @Gordatron I guess it's the same for answers, though I'm not sure that user can cast deletion votes on answers.

Comment: @Emre why rude? Moderators keep the place clean by deleting low quality answers.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I do not think that a person who is a user of SO for more than 1 year would answer his own question with useless information.And if an answer is not useless then it is not a low quality answer, it could have some features which somehow, may help others with even the tiniest word in it, on their way

Comment: @Emre I was talking in general. Of course that valid answer by OP should not be removed, anyhow it's not relevant as such thing didn't happen on that specific question.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard my comment was for this specific situation.In general, SO sites and SO users owe their peace to moderators and to those who is determined to bring peace on SO users with flagging.

Answer (score 1):

You can see your deleted answers.

(Not in your listing, just when you look at the question).

Comment: where would they appear? edits on the question are detailed on a page you get to through a link on the time of an edit but i cant see anything for deleted answers (no saying it isn't there, i've missed plenty of cool buttons on web apps ;-)

Comment: @gordatron, they'd just look like answers, but grayed out.

Comment: cool, as a little test can someone delete my answer from this question... i will add one now

Comment: Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead. BOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Comment: maybe later then....

Comment: @gord but you asked it 20 hours ago... ?

Comment: i was trying to do the test on this one.. its a separate account to my stack overflow account which i can answer questions straight away on.